# How to compress the main folder which includes certain sub folder using tar

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Assume we have a folder structure as below

```
main_folder
   - sub_folder1
   - sub_folder2
   - sub_folder3
        - valid_folder1
        - valid_folder2
        - junk_folder1
        - junk_folder2
    - sub_folder4
```

How to compress all the folders and files in the `main_folder` using `tar` command however include only `valid_folder1` and `valid_folder2` from `sub_folder3`

I understand we can exclude those junk folders using `--exclude` option.  But those junk folders are dynamic in nature and it is not possible to use the exclude option.

Answer (score 0):

You could on the `tar` command specify multiple `-exclude` parameters
with regex like:
`--exclude='*sub_folder1*' --exclude='*sub_folder2*'`.

This way `tar` will exclude the folders you don't want and include
only the folders whose names are not implied by the `exclude` regexes.

For more information see:

- [tar(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)
- [6.4 : Excluding Some Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html)

Comment: As mentioned in my post I cannot use exclude option.  The folder names are dynamic and not on a single pattern.

Comment: You would need to define using regex/regexes either the junk files or the good files. You may use the regex(es) for the junk files in `--exclude`, or use the regex for the good files in one or more `find` commands that will create an input file for `tar`.